# Name for major/minor ambiguity in cadence

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony, cadence

Is there a name for a cadence which ends on I or i, but with the third intentionally omitted, so as to leave the final chord ambiguous between major and minor? Or a general term for using the tonic chord with the third omitted in a context where a major/minor third would be expected?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard them referred to as "fifth chords", "power chords" and "no3 chords".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to prooffreader's answers, the most common term that I've heard is "open fifth." The idea is that there is a fifth (say, C/G) that lacks the middle third (hence "open").

In analysis, these chords are sometimes identified as `C5`, indicating the only chord tone is the fifth above the bass. (This is in contrast to `5/3` figured bass, which suggests both a fifth *and* a third above the bass.)

Regarding a cadence that uses this, you may consider the general term "attenuated cadence," which simply refers to a cadence that is somehow weakened from its more normative form.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the Quintal harmony, mostly used in Jazz harmony. It is the harmonic structure preferring the perfect fifth, the augmented fifth and the diminished fifth.

Perhaps you find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal_and_quintal_harmony) article more helpful

Answer (score 0):

If it is the end of a three voice harmonic progression it is acceptable for the I to consist entirely of a tripled root. Also, strict counterpoint must end on a perfect consonance (excluding perfect fourths) this naturally results in the chord in question when the last I is just a fifth. I wanted to point out that a I5 does not imply ambiguity between major and minor. You could use it as a common chord for mode mixture to the parallel minor of your starting key. A smoother alternative to this would be using the V as a common chord followed by iv i (plagal progression in minor) this should result in a smooth mode mixture without too much resultant stability thus allowing flirtation with major or with other keys. It could serve as the departure for a developement section.